# ndk-build not calling function properly

Tags: android-ndk, cygwin

I followed the tutorial found on http://android.wooyd.org/JNIExample/ and when I try to build with cygwin i get:

```
undefined reference to `android::AndroidRuntime::registerNativeMethods(_JNIEnv*, char const*, JNINativeMethod const*, int)'
```

in the includes i found the registerNativeMethods function as declared below:

```
static int registerNativeMethods(JNIEnv* env,
    const char* className, const JNINativeMethod* gMethods, int numMethods);
```

I don't see why the compiler is reading the inputs to the function as char const * and JNINativeMethod const* when I pass it a const char * and a JNINativeMethod []. Although I looked and found places where it says that char const * and const char * are the same. If so why am I getting this error.

If it makes a difference my entry point for the ndk is a c++ file and im using stock cygwin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

registerNativeMethods is implement in libandroid_runtime.so, which can't be found in ndk.

the sample have declared that:
If you are coding for firmware 1.5 or newer, it is strongly recommended to use Android NDK instead of following this guide.

so the guide is not for ndk use, is for android source code build